# How to add new field beside other field in admin form

Tags: magento-1.8

I have some form filed in my custom module in magento backoffice and I want to add filed that will be shown just beside first filed, not under. Is that possible and how? Now I have:

```
    $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('mymodule_test')->__('Name'),
        'name'  => 'name',
        'required'  => true,
        'class' => 'required-entry',
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `after_element_html` key. But the problem is that you have to write the html manually.  Something like

```
$fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('mymodule_test')->__('Name'),
    'name'  => 'name',
    'required'  => true,
    'class' => 'required-entry',
    'after_element_html' => '<input type="text" name="some_name" class="some class" />'
));
```